# Make dynamic AlertDialog with checkboxes of ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: android

I am trying to build an dynamic dialog window "Which number would you take" in my `onNewIntent` method for any Integer ArrayList for example `[1,9,13]` but I dont know how can I get it to work since it is dynamic

onNewIntent method:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

         // getIntent() should always return the most recent
        setIntent(intent);

        //I added here this part to receive the intent from onPostExecute //
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            ArrayList<Integer> routeList = extras
                    .getIntegerArrayList("stop_route");
            for (int item : routeList) {
               // System.out.println("The Intent is not empty: " + item);
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                checkbox.setId(item);
                checkbox.setText(item);


            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating `AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` in for-each loop? where are you adding your CheckBoxes to AlertDialog ??

Comment: @Mithun: Ich will take the `AlertDialog` out of the for loop. I want to add the checkboxes to the dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that MaterialDialog extends DialogBase, which extends AlertDialog. While a very small number of the stock methods are purposely deprecated and don't work, you have access to methods such as dismiss(), setTitle(), setIcon(), setCancelable(), etc. Alternatives are discussed below.

Here's a basic example that mimics the dialog you see on Google's Material design guidelines (here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-usage). Note that you can always substitute literal strings and string resources for methods that take strings, the same goes for color resources (e.g. titleColor and titleColorRes).

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
    .title(R.string.title)
    .content(R.string.content)
    .positiveText(R.string.agree)
    .negativeText(R.string.disagree)
    .show();
```

On Lollipop (API 21+) or if you use AppCompat, the Material dialog will automatically match the positiveColor (which is used on the positive action button) to the colorAccent attribute of your styles.xml theme.

If the content is long enough, it will become scrollable and a divider will be displayed above the action buttons.

You can refer this github link
https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Comment: but how can I get the ArrayList content as checkboxes in the MaterialDialog ? That is my problem.